# jQuery ajax: sourcing url from variable does not work - same hard-coded url does - why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When trying to set and get the url for a jQuery Ajax (post) call, I thought it would be useful to allow the dynamic setting of the url the request gets sent to, as follows:

set the url to 'store.php' in a div with id 'store'

```
<div id='store'>store.php</div>
```

and then use it in the jQuery Ajax call, by pulling the value from the div with id 'store':

```
var store = $('#store').val(); // the url path to store.php
$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  data: "html",
  //url: "store.php", // SUCCESS - status: success, alert 'content saved' is triggered, i.e. we received msg 'content saved' back from store.php
  url: store, // FAILURE - status: success, alert 'an error occured' is triggered, do NOT receive msg back from store.php
  data: {
    content: content,
    slug: slug,
    articleId: articleId
  },

  success: function(data, status) {
    if (data == "content saved") {
      alert('your content is saved');
    } else {
      alert('an error occured...');
    }
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'STATUS: ' + status;
    document.getElementById('success').innerHTML = 'RESPONSE FROM SERVER: ' + data;
  },

  error: function(xhrobj, status) {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'ERROR handler says: ' + status;
  }
})
```

Using the hard-coded url: 'store.php' works, I get a message back from store.php, but when I use the 'store.php' from the div it doesn't.

Conclusion: I'd like to dynamically retrieve the url from a div (or e.g. hidden form-field), similar to the way I've shown here, as it would allow me to change the target php-file with ease.

Any thoughts welcome, thanks very much in advance

Comment: Use `.text()`, not `.val()`. `.val()` is for user inputs.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks that solved it

Comment: BTW, when you were debugging this, did you try `console.log(store)`? Why not?

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, should have - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

`.val();` does not retrieve the text content of an element - it returns the `value` of the element. (valid for elements such as inputs and textareas, but not for generic `div`s)

Retrieve the text of the element instead:

```
var store = $('#store').text();
```

or, better, without jQuery:

```
var store = document.querySelector('#store').textContent;
```